# Android - EditText delete (soft button) key event and deleting action

Tags: android, android-edittext, keylistener

In my fragment, I want to intercept the event "delete (soft button) pressed" from the software keyboard, on an EditText.

I can do that, using the following code:

```
positionEditText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
                Log.d("TAG", "OnKeyListener, premuto BACKSPACE");
                backspacePressed = true;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

The problem is that doing so, I can't properly delete the edit text. The deleting function only works if I press and hold the delete button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
    Log.d("TAG", "OnKeyListener, premuto BACKSPACE");
    backspacePressed = true;
    return true; // This is the problem
}
```

By returning **true**, *you are telling system that.. I'm going to handle that*. Remove it and it will work.

Comment: @RajeshKushvaha What is your problem? For my issue, that solution perfectly works.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
positionEditText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
                Log.d("TAG", "OnKeyListener, premuto BACKSPACE");
                backspacePressed = true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```